# usar o dapper com arquivo txt e nao banco de dados

Tags: datagridview, txt, dapper

saudações como posso usar o dapper com um arquivo texto e nao uma tabela ou banco de dados,
preciso manipular e alterar varias linhas desse texto.

Tenho um form onde abro um txt em um datagrid com vários lançamentos(data, histórico e valor),
nao e o banco ainda ai crio um dataset na memoria ou seja nao conectei nada ainda.
preciso fazer as pesquisas nesse dataset para corrigir esse txt. nao é banco de dados ainda.

obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: se não é um banco de dados, vc não precisa de um ORM... carrega os dados em listas na memória e faz o que precisa ser feito...

Comment: Obrigado Rovann por responder, entendo o que vc disse, como existe a ideia de criar datasets na memoria pensei que pudesse fazer o mesmo só pra facilitar entende?